# ddl in code or script

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, ddl

I need to run ddl commands (e.g. CREATE, DROP) during application flow (not just one-time initialiation). Is it better to write one big .sql script to do it and run the script from code using a command line, or is it preferred to run each sql command separately from my java/c# code?

one big .sql pros:

- script can be easily reused by dba, and by developers during development
- easier to edit large sql in a native editor

one big .sql cons:

- My application will executes an external .sql script via command line. If anything fails, I have no way to know where exactly it failed (either than parsing logs) or take a specific application action after a failure of a particular command

Comment: Check out tools like Liquibase or Flyway

Comment: thanks, my use case is not database migration, I will use FlyWay for that use case. my use case is that for optimization certain user activities need to create or drop tables.

Comment: Creating and dropping tables "on-the-fly" is usually not such a good idea. Why can't you create those tables using your regular migration scripts?

Comment: thanks, there are specific optimization issues in this system, and dbas and architects all agreed that it is right for us. now I need to know if it is best to use one big .sql or code according the considerations I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I would use prcedural language API (package or some set of functions and procedures) on DB side for creating and dropping these tables.

It allows you to execute these in creator privileges, and avoids potential security risk on the application side.